# Recalling system info in PS

Tags: powershell-5.0

I'm sure this is an easy one for the community, but it's got me puzzeled.

If I create a var in PS, say "$s" then assign "systeminfo /s {hostname}" to the var (`$s = systeminfo /s {hostname}`) -- how do I pull a single bit of info out of that var to display?

For example: after I've run the cmd to populate the var I want to return only the system boot time.

```
$s = systeminfo /s majorsys01
"$s.System Boot Time" doesn't return anything.
```

So, how would I output that type of data? Get-Aduser works really well for that, but there aren't any spaces in that output and those are all fields reporting back.

Thanks,
Dale

Comment: Rather than parsing string data, why not (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-get-the-last-boot-time-with-powershell/) ?

Comment: `Get-ADUser` is a proper Powershell cmdlet. `systeminfo` is not. That’s the difference. You cannot make a Powershell cmdlet without programming.

Answer (score 1):

'Get-AdUser' works not because there aren't any spaces, but because the data it retrieves *remains* separate fields all the way through – the result is generated internally as a PowerShell object, with each LDAP attribute stored in its own field. (The table you see is generated dynamically on output; it's not actually *stored* as "field: value" text internally.)

With 'systeminfo', however, the output of an external .exe program is always flattened into a single large string – PowerShell is completely unaware that it *had* separate fields at all. The only way to extract something from it is via string parsing (i.e. regex the needed data out of the wall-of-text line by line).

Ideally, you should find a way that *doesn't* use any external programs like 'systeminfo' – instead retrieve the needed data existing functions that PowerShell itself already has available (or if necessary, calling out to Windows API).

For example, if it is something available via WMI, then you can do a direct WMI query using `Get-WmiObject` (newer versions use `Get-CimInstance`) and you'll get an object that retains its separate properties.

As in Keith's comment, most of the basic data that 'systeminfo' retrieves is indeed available through WMI/CIM, so you should start with calling Get-CimInstance:

```powershell
$s = gcim -ComputerName majorsys01 Win32_OperatingSystem

$s | get-member -membertype property

$s | fl *

$s.LastBootupTime
```

If a built-in cmdlet is not available, the next step would be to look for a .NET (C#) function (all of which are accessible directly from PowerShell), or for native Windows API functions (also accessible from .NET, though that's a bit more effort) – for most tasks, someone has probably written a module in PSGallery for it.

If calling an external program is the only way, then see if it can be told to output data in **machine-readable format** such as JSON or XML or CSV. For example, 'systeminfo' supports the `/fo csv` option which gives you the same fields in a standard format that PowerShell can then parse:

```powershell
$text = systeminfo /fo csv

$obj = ConvertFrom-Csv $text

$obj | get-member

$obj."System Model"
```

As a last resort, if the data is neither available via more direct means (WMI or other APIs) nor in standard formats (JSON or CSV), you can use string parsing (e.g. [-match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3)) to try to extract the necessary bits out of the program's output.